# Black screen in MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios

i want to play video from the server in iOS. i have implemented the following code

```
MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                  initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"]];
[movie.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movie];
[movie  play];
[self.view addSubview:movie.view];
```

But i am getting a black screen. while i implement it with the AVPlayer It works why is it so?

Comment: can you try to remove this line?  `[self.view addSubview:movie.view];`

Comment: even though its not working

Comment: create object of MPMoviePlayerController *movie; in h file,, then use this object.

Comment: If you are targetting iOS 9 you should consider using `AVPlayerViewController` instead, as `MPMoviePlayerController` is deprecated in iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

First retain your movie player object.
Use this line in h file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController * movie;
```

Then use this object in m file. Use this line as well.

```
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```